# Laravel WebSockets is closed before the connection is established

Tags: laravel, apache, websocket, proxy, mapping

I have Managed VPS and i encountered this error when i try to use websockets with apache.
here is my env part. i have configured seperate subdomain for websockets which have its own ssl. and in combined file i have both cert and private key.

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/wss.mbaye.ml/combined
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/wss.mbaye.ml/combined
```

here is websockets part.

```
'dashboard' => [
        'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    ],

    'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => env('WEBSOCKETS_URL') // for dashboard
    ],
],
'ssl' => [
    
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),
    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),
    'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
    'verify_peer' => false,
],
```

Here is broadcasting.php.

```
'connections' => [

     'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'https',
             'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

here is bootstrap.js file.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

and i didn't change anything in apache configuration.
can anyone tell me where i am doing something wrong.??

Comment: In `.env` file, did you change your broadcast driver to pusher?  `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

Comment: yes i have changed it already but still the same error.

Comment: do we need to configure apache for some kind of maping also.??

Comment: Did you start WebSocket server using `php artisan websockets:serve`?

Comment: yes i have tried but then it stuck on running websockets on 6001 port.

Comment: Was your server started? You could use 'telnet' to check connection.

Comment: yes server was started website is working properly but the issue is related to websockets.